# Match "de" after abc in regular expression?

Tags: regex

I have a string `"ABB"`, and I want to match the `"B"` after the `"A"`.

1. Is it possible?
2. If it is possible, how could I do this?

P.S.: I know to I could use the `"A(B)"` to match `"AB"` and to extract the `"B"` in the group. But I am using it in a text editor, so I cannot use the group technique.

Comment: What texteditor are you using? All editors supporting regex should also support groups. I guess you need it for replacing, you should be able to replace `(A)B` with `$1C` to replace all Bs after A with Cs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use positive look-behind assertion for that:

```
(?<=A)B
```

This will match only B without matching A. `(?<=A)` makes sure that B is preceded by A.